# ebean query with subquery

Tags: sql, ebean

I'm trying to do using EBean the equivalent of

```
select * from myTable1 where id not in (select id2 from myTable2) ;
```

I have no reference of table1 Object in table2 Object and the same the other way around.
Does anyone knows how to that using EBean ?

For the moment all I have is :

```
List<MyTable1> myResult = MyTable1.find.where().eq("id","1" ).findList();
```

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it has been possible to do this since 2009 using the example given in this bug report:

http://www.avaje.org/bugdetail-92.html

**The example:**

```
Query<Product> subQuery =   
    Ebean.createQuery(Product.class)  
        .select("sku")  
        .where().idEq(4).query();  

List<MinCustomer> list = Ebean.find(MinCustomer.class)  
    .where().in("name", subQuery)  
    .findList();
```

**However:**

I am unable to make it work because the SQL generated is invalid. Seemingly due to a string replacement happening behind the scene in Ebean where (for me at least) the table name in the subquery is lost.

I expect it has to do with my main query includes a reference to the table from which my subquery "is selecting".

Turning the valid SQL from the example:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.notes   
from o_customer c   
where  (c.name) in (select p.sku  from o_product p  where p.id = ?  )
```

... into this invalid SQL in my case:

```
select t0.id as c0, ... t0.location_id as c8
from myRecordClass t0
where  (t0.location_id) in (
    select t0.id
    from t0.location_id t0    # should be: from location t0
    where t0.customer_id = ?
    )  and t0.creation > ?  
order by t0.creation desc
```

**The workaround:**

Use the RawSql approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431625/190599 - example here:

```
String sql = "select b.id, b.location_id ... " +
        "from myRecordClass b " +
        "where location_id in (" +
            "select id " +
            "from location " +
            "where customer_id = " + user.getCustomer().getId() +
        ") " +
        "order by creation desc limit 10";

RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder
        .parse(sql)
        .columnMapping("b.id", "id")
        .columnMapping("b.location_id", "location.id")
        ....
        .create();

Query<MyRecordClass> query = Ebean.find(MyRecordClass.class);
query.setRawSql(rawSql);
final List<MyRecordClass> list = query.findList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hardly believe that [RawSql](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html) is fastest way to achieve this kind of query, it allows you to return list of mapped objects.

It's also possible to use `SqlQuery` (described in [Reference guide (PDF)](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html)) to fetch a list of `SqlRow`s - so you can find required data without any mapping at all.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found a way to do that using EBean, et not using rawsql. But thanks anyway.

Comment: `RawSql` comes from Ebeans API as well :) and there's nothing bad about using this.

Comment: @CC How did you end up doing it directly in ebean?